# How to add commas in between words in string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

#### I'm trying to add commas in between the first and last names in parentheses.

```
//Input:

s = "Fred:Corwill;Wilfred:Corwill;Barney:Tornbull;Betty:Tornbull;Bjon:Tornbull;Raphael:Corwill;Alfred:Corwill";

//Expected output: "(CORWILL, ALFRED)(CORWILL, FRED)(CORWILL, RAPHAEL)(CORWILL, WILFRED)(TORNBULL, BARNEY)(TORNBULL, BETTY)(TORNBULL, BJON)"
```

*What my code is **currently** outputting:*

```
(CORWILL ALFRED) (CORWILL FRED) (CORWILL RAPHAEL) (CORWILL WILFRED) (TORNBULL BARNEY) (TORNBULL BETTY) (TORNBULL BJON)
```

I've tried a number of approaches like changing how the characters are replaced in the beginning when I reassign s (the string) so that I am not removing the commas in the first place, to then have to replace them...but when I did that, the regex I have was no longer working, and I am not sure why that is. So I tried to find another regex to use so I could work around that problem, but that has equally been a pain, so I decided to just stick to solving it this way: trying to find a way to find commas in between the first, and last names in the parentheses.

**Full problem & code:**

```
/*Could you make a program that 
    •   makes this string uppercase
    •   gives it sorted in alphabetical order by last name. 
When the last names are the same, sort them by first name. Last name and first name of a guest come in the result between parentheses separated by a comma.
*/

function meeting(s) {

  s = s.replace(/:/g, ", ").toUpperCase();

  //order alphabetically based on Last, then first name
 const semicolon = ';'
 let testArr = s.split(semicolon)
  testArr.sort(function compare(a, b) {
      var splitA = a.split(",");
      var splitB = b.split(",");
      var firstA = splitA[0]
      var firstB = splitB[0]
      var lastA = splitA[splitA.length - 1];
      var lastB = splitB[splitB.length - 1];

      if (lastA < lastB) return -1;
      if (lastA > lastB) return 1; 

      if (firstA < firstB) return -1; //sort first names alphabetically
      if (firstA > firstB) return 1; 
      return 0; //if they are equal
  })
  //print last names before first names with regex
let newArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
  let variable = (testArr[i].replace(/([\w ]+), ([\w ]+)/g, "$2 $1"))
  let comma = ","
  newArr.push(`(${variable})`)
  }
  
let finalStr;
finalStr = newArr.toString().replace(/[ ,.]/g, " ").toUpperCase();
// finalStr = finalStr.replace(/" "/g, ", ")
return finalStr
}

s = "Fred:Corwill;Wilfred:Corwill;Barney:Tornbull;Betty:Tornbull;Bjon:Tornbull;Raphael:Corwill;Alfred:Corwill";

console.log(meeting(s))

// expected result: "(CORWILL, ALFRED)(CORWILL, FRED)(CORWILL, RAPHAEL)(CORWILL, WILFRED)(TORNBULL, BARNEY)(TORNBULL, BETTY)(TORNBULL, BJON)"
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've spent about 5 hours on this problem.The regex I am using is to switch the last name's position with the first name's position (Fred Corwill) --> (Corwill Fred). If there is a **regex** for me to this other than the one I am using that you could suggest, maybe I could work around the problem this way too, so far everything I have tried has not worked other the one I am using here.

Comment: You shouldn't need a regex at all for this.  You can do the whole thing with `split()` calls and string concatenation.

Comment: Could I use split() to switch the last name's position with the first name's position? (Fred Corwill) --> (Corwill Fred)

Comment: You know, some people do not hane only two names

Comment: Yeah definitely, that's a great point, but for this problem that's all I have to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks much more complicated than it needs to be. After splitting by `;`s, map each individual element to its words in reverse order, then join:

```js
const s = "Fred:Corwill;Wilfred:Corwill;Barney:Tornbull;Betty:Tornbull;Bjon:Tornbull;Raphael:Corwill;Alfred:Corwill";

const output = s
  .toUpperCase()
  .split(';')
  .sort((a, b) => {
    const [aFirst, aLast] = a.split(':');
    const [bFirst, bLast] = b.split(':');
    return aLast.localeCompare(bLast) ||  aFirst.localeCompare(bFirst);
  })
  .map((name) => {
    const [first, last] = name.split(':');
    return `(${last}, ${first})`;
  })
  .join('');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: That's a concise way to sort the names. `localeCompare` "returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before, or after, or is the same as the given string in sort order". If the last names are different, it'll sort the person whos last name comes first (by returning either 1 or -1). Otherwise, `localeCompare` will return 0, so it'll go on to do the same comparison with the first names.

Comment: Oh, forgot the comma - just put in the `,` when you're returning the mapped string

Comment: okay, this didn't have the commas so I added them, final code that works: `function meeting(s) {
const output = s
  .toUpperCase()
  .split(';')
  .sort((a, b) => {
    const [aFirst, aLast] = a.split(':');
    const [bFirst, bLast] = b.split(':');
    return aLast.localeCompare(bLast) ||  aFirst.localeCompare(bFirst);
  })
  .map((name) => {
    const [first, last] = name.split(':');
    return `(${last}, ${first})`;
  })
  .join('');
return output;
  }`

Comment: If you copy the result in the snippet, you'll see that it exactly matches what your `//Expected output:` says in the question - isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Quick question...when you use `const [aFirst, aLast]` or `const [first, last]` are you declaring both of those variables at once? (I've never seen that syntax) Also they are strings yes? And yes this solution works now, it wasn't before (the comma wasn't there, I added it, not sure how that happened), I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, when I said *just put in the , when you're returning the mapped string*

Comment: Quick question...when you use const [aFirst, aLast] or const [first, last] are you declaring both of those variables at once? (I've never seen that syntax) Also they are strings yes? And yes this solution works now, it wasn't before (the comma wasn't there, I added it, not sure how that happened), I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: The `split` returns an array containing two elements, Using `const [aFirst, aLast]` assigns the two elements of the array to those variables. It's like doing `const arr = a.split(':'); const aFirst = arr[0]; const aLast = arr[1];`

Comment: Also, I was using console.log right after this line, and saw that the line `const [first, last] = name.split(':');` wasn't what was replacing the colon from the string, the line after it was `return `(${last}, ${first})`;` so I'm wondering, is it the use of the comma in this template literal that is simply overriding the colon?

Comment: The `.split` removes the colon and gives an array of the two words around the colon. The words (with only those alphabetical characters) go into the two variables. Then the template literal returns those words with a comma between them.

Answer (score 0):

Using splits with maps and sorts

```js
var s = "Fred:Corwill;Wilfred:Corwill;Barney:Tornbull;Betty:Tornbull;Bjon:Tornbull;Raphael:Corwill;Alfred:Corwill";

var res = s.split(/;/) // split into people
  .map(x => x.split(/:/).reverse()) // split names, put last first
  .sort((a, b) => a[0] === b[0] ? a[1].localeCompare(b[1]) : a[0].localeCompare(b[0])) // sort by last name, first name
  .map(x => `(${x.join(', ')})`) // create the new format
  .join(' ') // join the array back into a string
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how this fits into the rest of my code to be honest, so they can still be alphabetically ordered and everything. When I insert it as the last line, right before return, it removes the effect of the alphabetical ordering and the regex. Any clue as to where this would fit in? /:

Comment: But this updated solution isn't accounting for the fact that they have to be alphabetical by last name, and then first name too /: still trying to figure it out.

Comment: @grimreaper there was a typo in it that caused it sort by last name twice. Copy paste fail..... whooops

Answer (score 0):

That's what you need:

```js
const str = 'Fred:Corwill;Wilfred:Corwill;Barney:Tornbull;Betty:Tornbull;Bjon:Tornbull;Raphael:Corwill;Alfred:Corwill';

function formatString(string) {
  const modifiedString = string.toUpperCase().replace(/(\w+):(\w+)/g, '($2, $1)');
  const sortedString = modifiedString.split(';').sort().join('');
  
  return sortedString;
}

console.log(formatString(str))
```